# ActiveAdmin with client side validation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin, client-side-validation

How can I set up my ActiveAdmin forms to use client side validation?  More specifically, how do I pass the `:validate => true` option that [Client Side Validation](https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations#usage) needs to the [form method](http://www.activeadmin.info/docs/5-forms.html) specified in Active Admin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the only way is to use the ActiveAdmin `form partials` http://activeadmin.info/docs/5-forms.html

```
  ActiveAdmin.register Post do
    form :partial => "form"
  end
```

/app/views/admin/posts/_form.hrml.erb

```
  <%= semantic_form_for [:admin, @post], remote: true, validate: true do |f| %>
    <%= f.inputs :title, :body %>
    <%= f.actions :commit %>
  <% end %>
```

**EDIT**
if a form in ActiveAdmin is in partial that you want to customize, you can use rails form builder `form_for` instead of `semantic_form_for`:

```
<%= form_for @post, :validate => true do |f| %>
  <%= f.submit 'Submit' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: also, if this will not work with `semantic_form_for` I remeber using a simple `form_for` in partials, I mean if you load your form from partial you don't have to use semantic_form, instead use `form_for` and go with documentations for `client_side_validation`